# Is it worth to use prototype or should we use OOP for javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype-oriented

I am a developer for sometime now, and for the past few years I am using prototype framework and it's implementation for OOP, to be used in Javascript. I've used jquery and some other frameworks as well.

I 've been studying how js works and how differs from OOP, as it is a prototype oriented language. In my opinion is in fact a great concept, the prototype oriented language.

**Given the right attention to:**

- it was how the language was meant to be used, and so therefore is faster, more productive and theoretically, simpler and smoother.
- Every browser has its own implementation for how javascript is supposed to work, making sometimes impossible for having a concise code work in all browsers, or at least the majority.
- Usually those OOP frameworks (dojo.declare(), Js.Class, MooTools, etc) are more than suitable to make a nice work, and they are cross-browsers.


I can't help but wonder, is it worth to start making RIA's using javascript prototype oriented? Or Should I go for *Dojo.declare()*, *js.class* or some similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I don't think you must forfeit OOP when you program in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099/what-makes-a-language-object-oriented); I suggest you [embrace OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107464/is-javascript-object-oriented)!

- I prefer the [ExtJS library](http://www.extjs.com/) which provides classes, encourages subclassing, and provides a very nice example of a well-defined class hierarchy.
- [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/) provides examples of making member data and member functions private (no protected).
- Many people use JavaScript's prototype as a vehicle to implement inheritence; again see [Douglas Crockford](http://www.crockford.com/).
- Polymorphism is easy as JS is not strongly typed.

Also, many of the popular JavaScript libraries abstract browser differences from the developer; you will likely find few "ifs" in your code to compensate for differences in browsers should you choose to use a JS library.

Finally, here are some other [good resources from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908443/what-are-good-javascript-oop-resources).

Comment: Don't get me wrong, i find oop very dear to me. I just want to hear some opinions.

Comment: there are any prototype oriented frameworks for js? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Don't fear them.  Pick a library (e.g. jQuery, ExtJS, dojo), pick a debugger (e.g. FireBug), test your code frequently on the major browsers, bookmark http://www.quirksmode.org/, and I think you will find the experience fun!

Comment: All of the frameworks/libraries exploit prototypes - primarily for inheritance; you don't need to worry about finding a library created specifically for prototypes.  In fact, you may be programming for weeks or months before you encounter a situation where you need to understand the intimate details of prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

I was using prototype.js from last one year on a RIA. I am not used to the libraries which you are talking about , but i use jQuery. After learning how to use prototype.js i just avoided jQuery,. I was able to do anything use prototype.js, especially when scope really matters prototype handles it in such beautifully way. You can't find the replacement of **bind** method provided by prototype in any other libraries. It is very very useful. i suggest you to go with prototype without fear.. it is cool and so easy to handle.