# What are "sums-and-products" data structures?

Tags: data-structures, programming-languages, types, type-systems, algebraic-data-types

A [recent blog post on William Cook's Fusings](http://wcook.blogspot.com/) mentions:

> The key point is that structures in Ensō are viewed holistically as graphs, not as individual values or traditional sums-and-products data structures.

What are the traditional sums-and-products data structures he is referring to?

Comment: See also "algebraic data types", e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770/haskells-algebraic-data-types/5917133#5917133

Answer (score 103, accepted):

> What are the traditional sums-and-products data structures he is referring to?

In type theory, regular data structures can be described in terms of sums, products and recursive types. This leads to an *algebra* for describing data structures (and so-called *algebraic data types*). Such data types are common in statically typed functional languages, such as ML or Haskell.

**Products**

Products can be thought of as the type-theoretic view of "structs" or "tuples".

Formally, PFPL, Ch 14:

> The binary **product** of two types consists of ordered pairs of values, one from
> each type in the order speciﬁed. The associated eliminatory forms are projections, which select the ﬁrst and second component of a pair. The nullary product, or unit, type consists solely of the unique “null tuple” of no values, and has no associated eliminatory form.

**Sums**

Sum types express choice between variants of a data structure. Sometimes they are called "union types" (as in C). Many languages have no notion of sum types.

PFPL, ch 15:

> Most data structures involve alternatives such as the distinction between a
> leaf and an interior node in a tree, or a choice in the outermost form of a
> piece of abstract syntax. Importantly, the choice determines the structure
> of the value. For example, nodes have children, but leaves do not, and so
> forth. These concepts are expressed by sum types, speciﬁcally the binary
> sum, which offers a choice of two things, and the nullary sum, which offers
> a choice of no things.

**Recursive types**

Along with products and sums, we can introduce recursion, so a type may be defined (partially) in terms of itself. Nice examples include trees and lists.

```
 data List a = Empty | a : List a

 data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

**Algebra of sums, products and recursion**

Give a type, say `Int`, we can start building up a notation for algebraic expressions that describe data structures:

A lone variable:

`Int`

A product of two types (denoting a pair):

`Int * Bool`

A sum of two types (denoting a choice between two types):

`Int + Bool`

And some constants:

`1 + Int`

where `1` is the unit type, `()`.

Once you can describe types this way, you get some cool power for free. Firstly, a very concise notation for describing data types, secondly, some results transfer from other algebras (e.g. [differentiation works on data structures](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Etxa/publ/jpartial.pdf)).

**Examples**

The unit type, `data () = ()`

[image]

A tuple, the simplest **product type**: `data (a,b) = (a,b)`

[image]

A simple **sum type**, `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`

[image]

and its alternative,

[image]

and a **recursive type**, the type of linked lists: `data [a] = [] | a : [a]`

[image]

Given these, you can build quite complicated structures by combining sums, products and recursive types.
E.g. the simple notation for a list of products of sums of products: `[(Maybe ([Char], Double), Integer)]` gives rise to some quite complicated trees:

[image]

---

*References*

- Practical Foundations for Programming
  Language, Robert Harper, 2011, [http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/plbook/book.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erwh/plbook/book.pdf)
- Quick intro to the algebra of data types, http://blog.lab49.com/archives/3011 ***(Link appears to be dead. Internet Archive link: http://web-old.archive.org/web/20120321033340/http://blog.lab49.com/archives/3011)***
- Species and Functors and Types, Oh My!, Brent Yorgey, [http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~byorgey/papers/species-pearl.pdf](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebyorgey/papers/species-pearl.pdf) -- has a very good overview of the algebra, Haskell data types, and the connection with *combinatorial species* from mathematics.

Comment: Where did you get all those pictures?

Comment: They're generated via `dot` by walking the data structure in the Haskell heap, using a library called [vacuum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum-cairo).

Comment: There is also this talk explaining this topic intuitively: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YScIPA8RbVE

Answer (score 47):

Very detailed answers have already been given, but somehow they don't mention this simple fact.

Sum types are called so because the *number of possible values* of a sum type is the **sum** of the number of values of the two underlying types.
Similarly for product types, the number of possible values is the product.

This stems from type theory defining a type as a set of values.

```
data MySumType = Foo Bool | Bar Char
data MyProductType = Baz (Bool, Char)
```

- Bool is a set of 2 values.
- Char is a set of 256 values.
- MySumType is a set of 2 + 256 values.
- MyProductType is a set of 2 * 256 values.

Now you will never forget which is which.

Comment: This is the most intuitive answer ever !

Answer (score 5):

He is referring to the standard [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) of functional programming languages.

Examples:

- If `a` is of type `A` and `b` is of type `B` then `(a, b)` is of type `A x B`, which is a [product type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type).
- A list type with values of the form `Nil` or `Cons x xs` is a [sum type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_type).

Ensō apparently has a greater emphasis on graphs than these tree-like algebraic types.

Answer (score 1):

From the lecture notes for the Coursera course, "Programming Languages", offered by Univ. of Washington:

"Why product and sum? It is related to the fact that in Boolean algebra where 0 is false and 1 is true, and works like multiply and or works like addition."