# Sum or Product Type?

Tags: scala, algebraic-data-types

Given the following [Algebraic Data Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911267/what-are-sums-and-products-data-structures):

```
scala> sealed trait Person
defined trait Person

scala> case class Boy(name: String, age: Int, x: String) extends Person
defined class Boy

scala> case class Girl(name: String, age: Int, y: Boolean) extends Person
defined class Girl
```

Note - I know that it's not a Recursive Type - there's no recursion involved.

So, is this a `Sum` or `Product Type`? Why?

Comment: Both—it's a sum of products. The [Wikipedia entry on ADTs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Also note that it could be recursive and still be a sum of products.

Comment: @TravisBrown: you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @TravisBrown - a `case object` or `case class` with a single argument comprise the `Sum Type` *class* in Scala?

Comment: @KevinMeredith You can think of sum as "or"—a `Person` is a `Boy` _or_ a `Girl` in this model. "and" is product—the `Boy` data type is made up of a name _and_ an age _and_ a string `x`.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `Person` can be considered as a sum type since an instance of it is either `Boy` or `Girl`.

`Boy` (or `Girl`) is a product type since an instance of `Boy` is a combination of type `String`, `Int`, and `String`.

Here is a very nice article about this "hybrid" case [Algebraic Data Types in Scala](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/algebraic-data-types-adts-in-scala)